# Books about the "Science" in Data Science?

Tags: statistics, reference-request

What are the books about the science and mathematics behind data science? It feels like so many "data science" books are programming tutorials and don't touch things like data generating processes and statistical inference. I can already code, what I am weak on is the math/stats/theory behind what I am doing.

If I am ready to burn $1000 on books (so around 10 books... sigh), what could I buy?

Examples: Agresti's [Categorical Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470463635), [Linear Mixed Models for Longitudinal Data](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441902996), etc... etc...

Comment: Asking about "good" books will attract opinion-based answers and so this is off-topic. Flagged.

Comment: I've changed it so I am just looking for books. Nothing opinion-based.

Comment: It's spelled S-t-a-t-i-s-t-i-c-s :)   Stick with something pragmatic that focuses on prediction rather than inference. Both _Elements of Statistical Learning_ and _An Introduction to Statistical Learning_ are on most people's lists.

Comment: I can't add a comment yet, but just FYI ESL is [available for free online as a pdf](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)

Comment: I think this question should be marked as community wiki.

Answer (score 23):

Introductory:

- [Machine Learning: The Art and Science of Algorithms that Make Sense of Data (Flach)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107422221)
- [Learning From Data (Abu-Mostafa et al.)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600490069)
- [Introduction to Statistical Learning (James et al.)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461471370)

Digging deeper:

- [Elements of Statistical Learning (Hastie et al.)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387848576)
- [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning (Bishop)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387310738)

Some special interest examples:

- [Convex Optimization (Boyd)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521833787)
- [Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning (Barber)](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.barber/brml/)
- [Probabilistic Graphical Models (Koller)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262013193)
- [Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition (Bishop)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198538642)

Broader reference works on machine learning (not really what you asked for, but for completeness):

- [Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective (Murphy)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262018020)
- [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach (Russell & Norvig)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136042597)

Bonus paper:

- [Statistical Modeling: The Two Cultures (Breiman)](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1009213726)

Comment: +1 for the bonus paper. Great read

Answer (score 14):

If I could only recomend one to you, it would be: [The Elements of Statistical Learning and Prediction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387848576) by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman.  It provides the math/statistics behind a lot of commonly used techniques in data science.

For Bayesian Techniques, [Bayesian Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439840954) by Gelman, Carlin, Stern, Dunson, Vehtari and Rubin is excellent.

[Statistical Inference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534243126) by Casella and Berger is a good graduate-level textbook on the theoretical foundation of statistics.  This book does require a pretty high level of comfort with math (probability theory is based on measure theory, which is not trivial to understand).

With respect to data generating processes, I don't have a recommendation for a book.  What I can say is that a good understanding of the assumptions of the techniques used and ensuring that the data was collected or generated in a manner that does not violate those assumptions goes a long way towards a good analysis.

Answer (score 8):

Other answers recommended a good set of books about the mathematics behind data science. But as you mentioned, its not just mathematics and activities like data collection and inference from data has their own rules and theories, even if not being as rigorous as mathematical backgrounds (yet).

For theses parts, I suggest the book [Beautiful Data: The Stories Behind Elegant Data Solutions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596157118) which contains twenty case-study like chapters written by people really engaged with real world data analysis problems. It does not contain any mathematics, but explores areas like collecting data, finding practical ways of using data in analyses, scaling and selecting the best solutions very well.

Another really interesting book is [Thinking with Data: How to Turn Information into Insights](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449362931), which is not technical (=programming tutorial) either, but covers important topics on how to really use the data science power in decision making and real world problems.

Answer (score 7):

I like Amir Ali Akbari's suggestions, and I'll add a few of my own, focusing on topics and skills that are not adequately covered in most machine learning and data analysis books that focus on math and/or programming.

Data Cleaning:

- [Osborne 2012, *Best Practices in Data Cleaning*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1412988012)
- [McCallom 2012, *Bad Data Handbook: Cleaning Up The Data So You Can Get Back To Work*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449321887)

Bayesian Data Analysis (alternative to Fisher-style Null Hypothesis Significance Testing):

- [Kruschke 2011, *Doing Bayesian Data Analysis*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123814855)

Inference in the face of uncertainty, incompleteness, contradictions, ambiguity, imprecision, ignorance, etc.:

- [Schum & Starace, 2001, *The Evidential Foundations of Probabilistic Reasoning*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0810118211)
- [Bammer & Smithson 2008, *Uncertainty and Risk: Multidisciplinary Perspectives*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1844074749)
- [Smithson 1989, *Ignorance and Uncertainty*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387969454)
- [CIA 2008, *A Tradecraft Primer: Structured Analytic Techniques for Improving Intelligence Analysis*](https://www.cia.gov/library/center-for-the-study-of-intelligence/csi-publications/books-and-monographs/Tradecraft%20Primer-apr09.pdf) (FREE! as PDF)
- [Morgan & Winship 2007, *Counterfactuals and Causal Inference: Methods and Principles for Social Research*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521671930)

Experiments:

- [Glennerster & Takavarasha 2013, *Running Randomized Evaluations: A Practical Guide*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691159270)
- [Dunning 2012, *Natural Experiments in the Social Sciences*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107698006)

Simulation:

- [Epstein 2006, *Generative Social Science: Studies in Agent-Based Computational Modeling*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691125473)
- [Nelson 2010, *Stochastic Modeling: Analysis and Simulation*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486477703)

Expert elicitation, probabilistic estimation:

- [Hubbard 2014, *How to Measure Anything: Finding the Value of Intangibles in Business*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118539273)